# multiple user identity in config Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-rbac

I developing a site with two different registrations, and I have 2 different table, Im using RbacDB, and in the web config in the components section I have user configuration, according to this I want to know how I can use 2 different fields in the config file?

config :

```
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
        'cookieValidationKey' => '213h2i3121h12osiajls',
    ],
    'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
    ],
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    ],
    // Here after user I need to add another config user-two
    'user-two' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\SecondUser',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    ],
```

when I do it, shows this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzVvj.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to set a class property in the user-two component:

```
'user-two' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\User'
    'identityClass' => 'app\models\SecondUser',
    'enableAutoLogin' => true,
],
```

or create new class inherited from the yii\web\User class and set like this:

```
'user-two' => [
    'class' => 'app\models\NewClassInheritedFromUserClass'
    ....
]
```

Maybe this will help you.

Comment: I tried both variants, error is gone, Tnx! but user stil not logged in

Comment: the better way is create new class inherited from the yii\web\User class. In this class you should override `public $identityCookie = ['name' => '_user_two_identity', 'httpOnly' => true];`, because the user and the user-two should have different cookies for authorization. after entering login and password look in the cookies. do you see the _user_two_identity cookie? by the way, somewhere in your code (in the LoginForm, i think) you should call `\Yii::$app->user-two->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);` (not Yii::$app->user->login(...))

Comment: Could someone provide a concrete example with code that uses two identities? I'm trying this, but I cannot seem to work it out. It seems that the second `yii\web\User` subclass works, but when I try to user AccessRule for a AdminController action, it fails, it does not understand that the user has already logged in, but using another identityClass and not the default one.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a web user class for the second identity

```
namespace app\components;

class UserTwo extends \yii\web\User{
}
```

than specify the class name in your config

```
'user-two' => [
        'class'=> 'app\components\UserTwo'
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\SecondUser',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through the yii2 framework internals. As I have understood, You can make N Identities following below technique;

---

- Above solutions are just the suggestions which are partial answers and some what helpful. kindly Follow my below changes in depth and you can create N identities as desired.
- N identities are very useful when you do not want to implement Complex RBAC (Role Based Access Control) and just want to Filter Access at controller's request.
- Let us Assume I have to create yet another Identity called '**Franchise**' other than existing User which is nicely coupled inside Yii2 Framework.

---

**DB Migrations**

1. Create a new migration file using command

   ```
   yii migrate/create create_franchise
   ```
2. Copy paste the content of already available migration file at location ***PROJECT_NAME\console\migrations*** something like '**m170311_105858_create_user.php**' and rename table name from 'user' to 'franchise'.
3. Now, run migration command

   ```
   yii/migrate
   ```

   - You must get something like this on command prompt

     ```
       Apply the above migrations? (yes|no) [no]:yes

       applying m170311_105950_create_franchise
       create table {{%franchise}} ... done (time: 1.304s)
       applied m170311_105950_create_franchise (time: 1.350s)
     ```
4. check DB whether DB is created. (I assume you have made DB settings in **PROJECT_NAME\common\config\main-local.php**)
5. Please note that whatever may be the Identity class, it shall now use  above 'Franchise' Table.

---

**Creating Franchise Model**

1. Just goto 'Gii' Module and create a model for newly create franchise table.
2. Model location must be **PROJECT_NAME\common\models\Franchise.php**
3. Make Sure that the Model class **implements IdentityInterface** and also implements mandatory methods of **IdentityInterface**

---

**Identity Class**

1. If you go to location **PROJECT_NAME\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\User.php**. This is the class that is referred everywhere in your project as  **Yii::$app->user**. Copy paste the content of this class and create a new File called **PROJECT_NAME\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Franchise.php** and paste the content in it. Make below changes in the file.

   - Find '**user**' and replace it with '**franchise**'.
   - Find '**User**' and replace it with '**Franchise**'.
   - Find **$loginUrl = ['site/login'];** and replace it with **$loginUrl = ['franchise/login'];** as you are going to have different controller to handle Franchise related actions.
   - Find **$identityCookie = ['name' => '_identity', 'httpOnly' => true];** and replace the '**name**' as '**_fidentity**' (you can see difference, identity cookie must be unique)
   - Find **$authTimeoutParam = '__expire';** and replace it with **$authTimeoutParam = '_f_expire';**

---

**PROJECT_NAME\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php**

1. In **Application.php** add below method,

   ```
   public function getFranchise()
   {
       return $this->get('franchise');
   }
   ```
2. Also find method **coreComponents()** and add one more entry as below,

   ```
   'Franchise' => ['class' => 'yii\web\Franchise'],
   ```

---

**PROJECT_NAME\frontend\config\main.php**

1. Inside **components** add below entry just after 'user' entry,

   ```
    'franchise' => [
           'identityClass' => 'common\models\Franchise',
           'enableAutoLogin' => true,
           'class' => 'yii\web\Franchise',
           'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_fidentity-frontend', 'httpOnly' => true],
       ],
   ```

Comment: If you modify PROJECT_NAME\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php, then on the next `composer update` you will lose any changes done in this file.